# Como realizar este ejercicio con arreglos en JAVA

Tags: java

He logrado avanzar un poco, he puesto las instrucciones de ingreso pero las instrucciones de cálculo no las puedo hacer :(
Ayuda por favor

```
/*
“El náufrago satisfecho” ofrece hamburguesas sencillas (S), dobles (D) y 
triples (T),
las cuales tienen un costo de $2.0, $3.5 y $4.8 respectivamente. 
La empresa acepta tarjetas de crédito con un cargo de 5 % sobre la compra. 
Lea datos de los N clientes, el tipo de hamburguesa y cantidad, 
la forma de pago (contado, tarjeta_crédito). 
Cada cliente adquiere una hamburguesa, las cuales pueden ser de diferente tipo, 
realice un programa para determinar cuánto deben pagar cada uno, si hay N 
clientes. 
También calcule cuantos clientes compraron hamburguesas: sencillas, dobles y 
triples.
Finalmente, presente el valor recaudado por la venta de las hamburguesas a los N 
clientes.
*/

package hamburguesa;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hamburguesa {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int longitud,compra2=0;
    String formadepago;
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos clientes desean comprar hamburguesa?: ");
        longitud=entrada.nextInt();
    }while(longitud==0);

    String clientes[]=new String[longitud];
    String rfc[]=new String[longitud];
    String tipohamburguesa[]=new String[longitud];
    for(int i=0; i<clientes.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del cliente "+(i+1)+":");
        clientes[i]=entrada.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el ruc o cedula para su factura: ");
        rfc[i]=entrada.next();
        System.out.println("¿Desea pagar en Efectivo o con Tarjeta?");
        System.out.println("1.Presione E para pagar en efectivo");
        System.out.println("2. Presione T para pagar con Tarjeta");
        formadepago=entrada.next();
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de Hamburguesa: ");
            System.out.println("1. Hamburguesa Sencilla--> Digite S");
            System.out.println("2. Hamburguesa Doble-----> Digite D");
            System.out.println("3. Hamburguesa Triple----> Digite T");
            tipohamburguesa[i]=entrada.next();
            switch (tipohamburguesa[i]){
                case "s":
                case "S":
                    tipohamburguesa[i] = "Sencilla";
                break;
                case "d":
                case "D":
                    tipohamburguesa[i] = "Doble";
                break;
                case "t":
                case "T":
                    tipohamburguesa[i] = "Triple";
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("¿Desea otra hamburguesa?");
            System.out.println("Presione 1 para aceptar...");
            System.out.println("Presione 2 para cancelar y facturar...");
            compra2=entrada.nextInt();
        }while(compra2==1);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<clientes.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Nombre Cliente: "+clientes[i]);
        System.out.println("Cédula: "+rfc[i]);
        System.out.println("Hamburguesa: "+tipohamburguesa[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: por favor no uses la etiqueta de javascript para preguntas que tienen código en Java

Comment: no se entiende tu actualización de la pregunta

Comment: explica de que hablas, cuando dices ordenes del docente

Comment: ¿por qué eliminar el contenido de la pregunta? Diría que esto es vandalismo, pero veo que la edición la ha hecho el propio autor... no me lo explico!

Comment: @jachguate es la misma duda que tengo, por que ahora nos menciona algo de qautoria y de docentes

Comment: No será que nos esta advirtiendo de que no copiemos el código que estaba antes por que es de su autoria?

Comment: La verdad no entiendo, he devuelto la pregunta a una versión anterior, de manera que las respuestas tengan sentido. En lo que a mi respecta, espero una explicación el OP sobre este comportamiento, la verdad no se explica.

Comment: @jachguate podrias eliminar esta pregunta por favor?

Comment: entonces vas a tener problemas de usar SO en español, aqui no se responden preguntas que cuando el OP(osea tu) obtiene respuesta la modifica, lee mas [tour] esto que haces no es correcto y con todo respeto si no quieres que te lo copien no lo hubieras preguntado @AndréRod542

Comment: @Andre, quizás no comprendes el funcionamiento de StackOverflow. Tu publicaste una pregunta (la decisión de publicar el código fue tuya). Hay miembros de la comunidad que se tomaron el tiempo de leer la pregunta y responderte. Este no es un servicio de escritura de datos ni de soporte técnico. La idea es que tu pregunta y las respuestas queden para futura referencia y consulta, sea esta de tus compañeros de clase o no. Como consejo, si no te gustaría que nadie copie tu código, no lo publiques. Un saludo.

Comment: además el código no es completamente tuyo, puesto que lo solucionaste con ayuda de alguien mas; entonces el primero que debería eliminar su respuesta es quien te dio la solución

Comment: Por lo mismo hablaré con él para eliminar el código o hablare directamente con SO para eliminar mi cuenta. Ponte por un momento en mis zapatos

Comment: no amigo @AndréRod542 no estas entendiendo así no se usa SO las preguntas y respuestas se quedan como fuente de conocimiento para todos y dado que piensas de esa manera no será conveniente publiques entonces tus tareas

Comment: Tranquilo amigo yo entiendo que te pongas a la defensiva, lo mejor será eliminar mi cuenta. No hay problema con eso

Comment: @AndréRod542, puedes eliminar tu cuenta si lo deseas, pero eso no eliminará la pregunta, ni sus respuestas. Por favor lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question (en inglés).

Comment: @AndréRod542, si no estás de acuerdo, siempre eres bienvenido en https://meta.es.stackoverflow.com, dónde se puede discutir el tema. Son las reglas del sitio. Esta es una comunidad y el objetivo acá es crear una base de datos de conocimiento para la humanidad. Se utiliza como pretexto las dudas de las personas, y está bien claro que tanto las preguntas como las respuestas son aportes a ese esfuerzo. Por eso se pide poner empeño, tanto en preguntar como en responder.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esto es una tarea escolar donde carece la existencia de código que demuestre al menos un intento de solucionar.

Comment: Exactamente, deseo que se cierre la pregunta señores

Comment: Muy importante: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: André, te recomiendo que leas [esto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2922/15301). Básicamente, tu pregunta no puede ser eliminada. Cuando publicas algo en [es.so],aceptas las normas del sitio. Si el código no debió ser publicado, tu eres responsable de ello. En la pregunta que te he dicho tienes un enlace al un formulario de contacto en el que puedes solicitar la eliminación de la pregunta, pero te advierto que es algo que rara vez sucede. Un saludo.

Answer (score 7):

Te comento, tienes harto código que esta demás en tu programa, te recomiendo que te limites a lo que te pide el problema. Todo lo de los datos de clientes te lo comente porque no es necesario para el calculo.

El calculo es sencillo, lo que necesitabas era instanciar variables de coste para cada tipo de hamburguesa y al momento de realizar cada pago calcular la suma de las hamburguesas compradas.

Otra cosa, como son solo 3 tipos de hamburguesas encontré que era mas viable guardar la cantidad de hamburguesas compradas de cada tipo, una en cada variable. Esto es cosa de gustos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hamburguesa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //int longitud,compra2=0; //el nombre de tus variables debe dar mas informacion sobre lo que hace
        int cantidadClientes;
        boolean continuarCompra=true;
        // falta el valor de cada hamburguesa
        final double s = 2;     //simple
        final double d = 3.5;   //doble
        final double t = 4.8;   //triple
        // lo que haria yo es crear un atributo de cantidad para cada tipo de hamburguesa.
        int cantS = 0 ,cantD = 0 ,cantT = 0;
        double gananciaTotal = 0;  // lo recaudado al final del dia
        double costePersonal = 0;      // el costo de lo comprado por persona
        String formadepago;
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("¿Cuantos clientes desean comprar hamburguesa?: ");
            cantidadClientes=entrada.nextInt();
        }while(cantidadClientes==0);

        //String clientes[]=new String[cantidadClientes];
        //String rfc[]=new String[cantidadClientes];
        //String tipohamburguesa[]=new String[cantidadClientes];//un cliente puede comprar mas de una hamburguesa por lo que este atributo no te sirve

        for(int i=0; i<cantidadClientes; i++){
            //System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del cliente "+(i+1)+":");//esto no te lo pide el problema
            //clientes[i]=entrada.next();
            //System.out.println("Ingrese el ruc o cedula para su factura: ");
            //rfc[i]=entrada.next();
            System.out.println("¿Desea pagar en Efectivo o con Tarjeta?");
            System.out.println("1.Presione E para pagar en efectivo");
            System.out.println("2. Presione T para pagar con Tarjeta");
            formadepago=entrada.next();
            do{ // falta validar esto
                System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de Hamburguesa: ");
                System.out.println("1. Hamburguesa Sencilla--> Digite S");
                System.out.println("2. Hamburguesa Doble-----> Digite D");
                System.out.println("3. Hamburguesa Triple----> Digite T");
                //tipohamburguesa[i]=;entrada.next()
                switch (entrada.next()){
                    case "s":
                    case "S":
                        //tipohamburguesa[i] = "Sencilla";
                        cantS++;
                        costePersonal += s;
                        break;
                    case "d":
                    case "D":
                        //tipohamburguesa[i] = "Doble";
                        cantD++;
                        costePersonal += d;
                        break;
                    case "t":
                    case "T":
                        //tipohamburguesa[i] = "Triple";
                        cantT++;
                        costePersonal += t;
                        break;
                    default:

                        break;
                }
                System.out.println("¿Desea otra hamburguesa?");
                System.out.println("Presione 1 para aceptar...");
                System.out.println("Presione 2 para cancelar y facturar...");
                if(entrada.nextInt()!=1) continuarCompra=false;
            }while(continuarCompra==true);
            //facturamos cliente por cliente
            System.out.println("Su compra tiene un coste de :"+costePersonal);//decimos al ciente cuanto salio su compra
            if(formadepago.equals("T")||formadepago.equals("t")){
                gananciaTotal += costePersonal * 0.95;  // si se con tarjeta se gana un 95%
            }else{
                gananciaTotal += costePersonal;
            }
            costePersonal = 0; //volvemos a instanciar el coste personal para cada cliente;
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
        System.out.println("Ganado al final del dia: " + gananciaTotal);

        //for(int i=0; i<cantidadClientes; i++){
            //System.out.println("Nombre Cliente: "+clientes[i]);
            //System.out.println("Cédula: "+rfc[i]);
            //System.out.println("Hamburguesa: "+tipohamburguesa[i]);
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndréRod542 no modifiques la respuesta eso es vandalismo

Comment: Esto es el colmo. ¿Piden que solucionen el problema y que borren la solución por motivos de plagio? Consejo para ti @AndréRod542, aprende a pensar y a leer la documentación de cualquier lenguaje de programación. Lee este post que redacté hace tiempo: http://fredyfx.com/post/gu%C3%ADa-r%C3%A1pida-para-nuevos-programadores/

Comment: no borres la respuesta @Cristian Figueroa, esto es parte de conocimiento colectivo, si el OP no comprendió como funciona SO en español es otro asunto y te doy un +1 por favor no la borres

Comment: tu viniste aqui a pedir ayuda @AndréRod542 no lo olvides

Comment: @shadow roguemos que este jaleo se solucione pronto, si apreció una pregunta así, existe una alta probabilidad que se genere otra similar...

Comment: por eso he solicitado la ayuda de los mod. por que considero una falta de respeto su proceder no solo por quien respondió sino por su último comentario aqui

Comment: Si es por mi no la volverá a haber, pueden desestabilizarme la cuenta si desean amigos. A la próxima voy a preguntar sin enunciado y como una pregunta general y estandar

Comment: Por cierto @AndréRod542, revisa esto: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/index.htm te será de utilidad para entender mejor a Java. http://tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/ Comparte con todos tus compañeros de clase. Entre mejor aprendan todos, más fácil podrán avanzar con la programación

Comment: Muy bien, lo guardaré en mis marcadores. Disculpen el mal rato que los he hecho pasar. Ya les dije que la solución esta en mi y en realizar el programa de otra forma para librarme del plagio

Answer (score -1):

Mira, te dejo una pequeña base, ya que tienes que ir guardando primero los datos luego imprimirlos, solo sigue añadiendo lo que requieras, y si no pues deja tu comentario.

```
public class Hamburguesa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int longitud;
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("¿Cuantos clientes desean comprar hamburguesa?: ");
            longitud=entrada.nextInt();
        }while(longitud==0);

        String clientes[]=new String[longitud];
        String RFC[]=new String[longitud];
        String tipohamburguesa[]=new String[longitud];
        for(int i=0; i<clientes.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del cliente "+(i+1)+":");
            clientes[i]=entrada.next();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el ruc o cedula para su factura: ");
            RFC[i]=entrada.next();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de Hamburguesa: ");
            System.out.println("1. Hamburguesa Sencilla--> Digite S");
            System.out.println("2. Hamburguesa Doble-----> Digite D");
            System.out.println("3. Hamburguesa Triple----> Digite T");
            tipohamburguesa[i]=entrada.next();
            /*if (tipohamburguesa=="S"){

            }*/
            switch (tipohamburguesa[i]){
                case "s":
                case "S":
                    tipohamburguesa[i] = "Sencilla";
                break;
                case "d":
                case "D":
                    tipohamburguesa[i] = "Doble";
                break;
                case "t":
                case "T":
                    tipohamburguesa[i] = "Triple";
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<clientes.length; i++){
            System.out.println("El cliente "+clientes[i]+" con RFC: "+RFC[i]+" adquirio una hamburguesa "+tipohamburguesa[i]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Con esa modificación estarías sobre escribiendo el dato de la variable anterior, por que hamburguesa[i] seguiría guardando el valor cada vez sobre si misma no? requieres que se puedan guardar hamburguesas ilimitadas?

Comment: Que presente cuantas simples, dobles o triples se vendieron y el valor recaudado de la venta de las hamburguesas que se vendieron,

Comment: si no mal recuerdo, tienes que trabajar con arreglos bidimensionales en ese apartado de las hamburguesas, por que si no sobreescribiras todo lo que vayas guardando, `tipohamburguesa[i]` siempre va a valer lo mismo dentro de ese ciclo, entonces si haces uno bidimensional `tipohamburguesa[i][j]` ese i siempre será el mismo, pero ahora lo identificarás con j para tener ambos datos `String[][] nombre = new String[i][j];` donde i es la cantidad de clientes, y j la cantidad de hamburguesas, podrías en lugar de pedir una y otra, que tecleen la cantidad de hamburguesas total y sea algo mas sencillo